# Changing target framework in visual studio

Tags: .net, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I'm getting the following warning while building an app in xamarin:

> " Package 'SQLite.Net-PCL 3.1.1' was restored using `.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1` instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project."

So, I installed the .net framework 4.6 developer pack.

Now, when I try to change the target framework in Properties-Applications, I can't find the 4.6 framework.

What did I miss here?

Comment: .net standard 2.0 support is already created, but [PR was not merged](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/pull/864)

Comment: I am having this same issue. I have other frameworks installed but they don't show up in the list of options. I followed tomer zeitune's instructions and installed additional frameworks, restarted VS and restarted my PC but still they don't show up.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to worry about these warnings, they usually don't cause a problem for you, stick with the framework that you prefer. Especially when using quickly changing frameworks you get these warnings all the time: **just ignore them**

If they still cause you trouble just

- Alt+Enter on the project
- Select "Application" on the sidebar
- Choose your preferred framework version form the combo-box

Answer (score 0):

In vs2015, Website > Startup Options > Build > Target Framework Dropdown